# Python simple Multi-threaded Downloader file corrupted

Tags: python, multithreading

This is my first post. I have been doing python programming for quite sometime and recently was working on a multi-threaded downloader. But the problem is that my file (jpg is my target ) gets corrupted . Also with the followinf input : http://www.aumathletics.com/images_web/headerAUMLogo.jpg

it shows error

while with the input :
http://www.nasa.gov/images/content/607800main_kepler1200_1600-1200.jpg

the file gets corrupted.

Here is the code:-

```
import os, sys, requests
import threading
import urllib2
import time

URL = sys.argv[1]

def buildRange(value, numsplits):
    lst = []
    for i in range(numsplits):
    if i == 0:
        lst.append('%s-%s' % (i, int(round(1 + i * value/(numsplits*1.0) +   value/(numsplits*1.0)-1, 0))))
    else:
        lst.append('%s-%s' % (int(round(1 + i * value/(numsplits*1.0),0)), int(round(1 + i * value/(numsplits*1.0) + value/(numsplits*1.0)-1, 0))))
return lst

def main(url=None, splitBy=5):
    start_time = time.time()
    if not url:
        print "Please Enter some url to begin download."
        return

fileName = "image.jpg"
sizeInBytes = requests.head(url, headers={'Accept-Encoding': 'identity'}).headers.get('content-length', None)
print "%s bytes to download." % sizeInBytes
if not sizeInBytes:
    print "Size cannot be determined."
    return

dataDict = {}

# split total num bytes into ranges
ranges = buildRange(int(sizeInBytes), splitBy)

def downloadChunk(idx, irange):
    req = urllib2.Request(url)
    req.headers['Range'] = 'bytes={}'.format(irange)
    dataDict[idx] = urllib2.urlopen(req).read()

# create one downloading thread per chunk
downloaders = [
    threading.Thread(
        target=downloadChunk,
        args=(idx, irange),
    )
    for idx,irange in enumerate(ranges)
    ]

# start threads, let run in parallel, wait for all to finish
for th in downloaders:
    th.start()
for th in downloaders:
    th.join()



print 'done: got {} chunks, total {} bytes'.format(
    len(dataDict), sum( (
        len(chunk) for chunk in dataDict.values()
    ) )
)

print "--- %s seconds ---" % str(time.time() - start_time)

if os.path.exists(fileName):
    os.remove(fileName)



# reassemble file in correct order
with open(fileName, 'w') as fh:

    for _idx,chunk in sorted(dataDict.iteritems()):
        fh.write(chunk)

print "Finished Writing file %s" % fileName
print 'file size {} bytes'.format(os.path.getsize(fileName))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main(URL)
```

the indentation here might be wrong so here is the code  pastebin(dot)com/wGEkp878

I would be very grateful if someone could point the error

EDIT: suggested by a guy

```
   def buildRange(value, numsplits):
     lst = []
    for i in range(numsplits):
        first = i if i == 0 else buildRange().start(i, value, numsplits)
        second = buildRange().end(i, value, numsplits)
        lst.append("{}-{}".format(first, second))
    return lst
```

can anyone tell me hoe to keep the part files downloaded with names like part1  part2 so on

Comment: As a first guess it looks like the buildRange function you have is more complicated that it should be, it might also be your problem. More over, and I'm sorry this isn't an answer to your questions, but multithreading a download like this will almost certainly take more time than doing it in a single request. The reason being that although all your data is being downloaded at the same time, you're still bandwidth limited and now you have many other things going on. It's a cool experiment though for certain, absolutely it's worth finishing.

Comment: can you tell me how to store the part files downloaded as part 1 2 3 4 etc?

Comment: Your original buildRange appeared to work, but the new one is much cleaner well done. The real problem appears to be that extra new line characters are getting added! Whenever a '\n' is encountered, an extra 0x0D is inserted before it.

Comment: how to solve it? also could you tell me how to save the part files downloaded as part 1 part 2 etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the file must be opened in binary mode, with 'wb' instead of 'w'. If opened with just 'w' a bunch of extra characters will be written. This has something to do with derpy windows vs. linux new line semantics. If you use 'wb' it will write exactly what you put in into the file.

EDIT:
If you want to store the individual file parts you can change

```
# reassemble file in correct order
with open(fileName, 'w') as fh:
    for _idx,chunk in sorted(dataDict.iteritems()):
        fh.write(chunk)

print "Finished Writing file %s" % fileName
print 'file size {} bytes'.format(os.path.getsize(fileName))
```

To

```
# reassemble file in correct order
for _idx,chunk in sorted(dataDict.iteritems()):
    with open(fileName + str(".part-") + str(_idx), 'wb') as fh:
        fh.write(chunk)

print "Finished Writing file %s" % fileName
#print 'file size {} bytes'.format(os.path.getsize(fileName))
```

Comment: still not getting correct file
102331 bytes to download.

done: got 5 chunks, total 102331 bytes

--- 1.9279999733 seconds ---

Finished Writing file image.jpg

file size 102948 bytes

Comment: I tried it on the few files you mentioned and it definitely writes the correct information to the file. Literally all you need to change is the line

with open(fileName, 'w') as fh:
 to
with open(fileName, 'wb') as fh:

Comment: thank you..could you also tell me how can i keep the part files too